# How to see if a matrix is block tridiagonal matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm using matlab and I have this square matrix. I need to check whether it is block tridiagonal (with block of size NxN) or not. Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a `[r x r]` matrix `A` and blocks of size `[N x N]` construct a block tridiagonal matrix of 1s and 0s `k` and compare indexes of nonzero elements of both matrices `A` and `k`:

```
r = size(A, 1);
Bin = ones(r/N, 3);
S = spdiags(Bin, -1:1, r/N, r/N);
k = kron(S, ones(N));
f = find(k);
fA = find(A);
is_A_block_tridiagonal = all(ismember(fA, f));
```